# Finding saddle point of indefinite quadratic function

Tags: optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

There are lot of material on internet how to find the minimum or maximum solution for  quadratic systems:
\begin{equation}
         f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}^T Q \mathbf{x} +  \mathbf{y}^T(A\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}) + c,
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{y}$ is a regularization parameter. Most of them $Q$ is positive definite or negative definite which we can find the optimal solution using for example using Conjugate Gradient. I got a very specific problem, where 
\begin{align}
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
-I & 0\\
 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
is a indefinite matrix ($I$ is the identity).

How can I find the optimal solution for non-convex problems? (saddle point?)

Comment: If the matrix is indefinite, then it seems entirely likely that the objective function isn't bounded above or below. For instance, if $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ (which is your $Q$ in the case $I=1$) then $f(x,0)$ yields arbitrarily large positive values and $f(0,y)$ yields arbitrarily large negative values. As such, there would be neither a maximum or a minimum if the domain is unrestricted. Minima/maxima will exist if you restrict the domain, of course.

Comment: In fact there is no maximum and no minimum. But I am looking for a method or derivation to find the saddle point.

Comment: Or at least converge to close the saddle point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling $X = (x,y)$ and $Y = \mu = (\mu_1,\mu_2)$ we have

$$
L(X,\mu)-x'\cdot x+y'\cdot y +\mu_1'\cdot(A_{11}\cdot x+A_{12}\cdot y-b_1) + \mu_2'\cdot(A_{21}\cdot x+A_{22}\cdot y-b_2)
$$

The stationary points for this lagrangian are given by the solutions for

$$
\cases{
-2 x'+\mu_1'\cdot A_{11} = 0\\
2y'+\mu_2'\cdot A_{22} = 0\\
A_{11}\cdot x+A_{12}\cdot y-b_1 = 0\\
A_{21}\cdot x+A_{22}\cdot y-b_2 = 0
}
$$

now solving for $\mu$

$$
\cases{
A_{11}A'_{11}\mu_1-A_{12}A'_{22}\mu_2 = 2b_1\\
A_{21}A'_{11}\mu_1-A_{22}A'_{22}\mu_2 = 2b_2
}
$$

and substituting into

$$
x = \frac 12 A'_{11}\mu_1\\
y = -\frac 12 A'_{22}\mu_2
$$

we get the stationary points.

Comment: Amazing answer! Last one, for complex values the calculation is the same? Can I consider (') as conjugate?

Comment: The $(\cdot)'$ indicates transposition.

Comment: So I can only use for Transpose not for Hermitian case?

Comment: You can use those rules in an hermitian system of course.

Comment: I mean in case for complex values I need to distinguish $\mathbf{x}^{H}$ and $\mathbf{x}$, which add more two variable $\mathbf{x}^{H}$ and $\mathbf{y}^{H}$. Am I right?

Comment: The hermitian transpose involves the conjugate operation. This transposition doesn't generate a new variable.

Comment: I was double checking your derivation. Well I am still have the problem if the system for $\mu$ is indefinite.  It not practical to solve if my system is sparse. Can't use for example a Steepest Descent or Conjugate Gradient.